# Vuex actions returns undefined and null

Tags: vue.js, authentication, axios, vuex

Hey guys I am creating a login with Vue, Vuex and Axios. But, when I press the login button instead of the users firstname being printed, it just prints the access token. Also, when I check in the devtools, it shows that some of the objects/variables are undefined. I am not sure why this is happening, hopefully you can help as it would be very appreciated.

index.js (Vuex):

```
import vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
import mutations from './mutations';


const createStore = () => {
  return new vuex.Store({
    state: {
      accessToken: "Hello",
      user: {
          dob: null,
          email: null,
          firstName: null,
          gender: null,
          id: null,
          lastName: null,
          profileImage: null,
          registered: null,
          verified: null
      }
    },
    getters: {
      accessToken: state => {
        return state.accessToken;
      },
    },
    actions: {
      init(store) {
        store.actions.setToken(store, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accessToken') || ''));
      },

      setToken(store, value) {
        store.commit('SET_TOKEN', value);
      },

      login(store, value){
          store.commit('SET_TOKEN', value);
          store.dispatch('pullUserDetails');
      },

      pullUserDetails(store){
        console.log(store);
        axios.get(
            'https://api.ticketpass.co/user',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization' : 'Bearer' + store.state.accessToken
                }
            }
        )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            store.state.user.dob = response.data.dob;
            store.state.user.email = response.data.email;
            store.state.user.firstName = response.data.firstName;
            store.state.user.gender = response.data.gender;
            store.state.user.id = response.data.id;
            store.state.user.lastName = response.data.lastName;
            store.state.user.profileImage = response.data.profileImage;
            store.state.user.registered = response.data.registered;
            store.state.user.verified = response.data.verified;
        },
        (error) => {
            error.response.id;
            error.response.firstName;
            error.response.lastName;
            error.response.email;
            error.response.profileImage;
            error.response.dob;
            error.response.gender;
            error.response.registered;
            error.response.verified;
        }
      );
    }
    },
    mutations
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

mutations.js

```
import { error } from "util";

const mutations = {
  setToken(state, token) {
    state.accessToken = token;
  },

  SET_TOKEN(state, value) {
    console.log(value);
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', value);
    state.accessToken = value;
    console.log(state.accessToken);
  },


};

export default mutations;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument you get in actions is `context` which has same properties as the `store` object.

In your `init` action you are doing

```
init(store) {
   store.actions.setToken(store, JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accessToken') || ''));
 }
```

where you are trying to dispatch `setToken` action.

But the `context` argument does not have an `actions` property.

To dispatch another action you shall use the `dispatch` method that the `context` argument gives you.

So in your `init` action

```
init(store) {
    store.dispatch('setToken', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accessToken') || ''));
  },
```

Reference- [vuex actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#actions)

Comment: Thanks for that. But, know I am trying to the word 'Login' and when the button is clicked it changes to 'Hi, User'                                    <div id="navigationUser">
<p v-if="$store.getters.getUserDetails.null" v-show='Login' /> 
                <p> Hi, {{$store.getters.getUserDetails.first_name}} <img class="userIMG" v-bind:src="$store.getters.getUserDetails.profile_image" /></p>
        </div>                                                                                                 But it is not working. Could please help. Many Thanks!